# Laptop won't turn on after forcing to shutdown

Tags: boot, laptop

First off, the laptop's a Lenovo B50-70.

Today I was using my Laptop to host a database server in my local network, letting it idle on my desk. When I wanted to turn it off the screen had turned off and wouldn't turn on, no matter what, so I had to perform a forced shutdown by holding the power button. This is an issue I had frequently since the upgrade to Windows 10. Only this time, the Laptop wouldn't turn on afterwards. No fans are starting and no lights turn on (except a blinking LED, see below).

I already took of the battery, tried to hold the power button for several seconds, put the battery back in. The usual stuff. I opened the laptop but couldn't find any obvious problems (Moreover, I lost two screws while doing this, even though being extra careful...).

When pressing the power button the power led on the side of the device blinks 3 times in succession. I believe this is the relevant error code. I do not have the manual anymore, nor do I find relevant information on the web, or in the online available manuals.

I am able to save the data on the hard drive myself, there is not even anything important data on this device. But it would be a huge inconvenience to not have the device available in the coming days.

Is there any chance I can fix this myself or is there no way around giving it to repair, based on your remote diagnosis?

P.S. As I am new to this stackexchange please feel free to add any relevant tags. I am struggling to choose appropriate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it looks like Flea power in the motherboard, though i noticed u did took off the battery and pressed the power button.

I think you should try the process for longer time like 1 or 2 minutes without the battery or the AC and nothing plugged in.

Also if this didn't work, check whether the battery is good or the AC charger is good you may need to try turn the pc with AC charger only (no battery)

Comment: Trying to turn it on without the battery did the trick. The strange thing is, that afterwards the laptop turned on even with the (supposedly broken) battery. I guess the remaining flea power just dissipated over time. Thanks.